# How to create a vector and output in reverse order

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, reverse

So I want to create a vector of 100 elements, then assign the first element to 1, the second element to 2, and so on. And then output this vector in reverse order so 100,99,98 and so on.
this is what I have, it keeps on outputting 0, any help would be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int>numbers(100);
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        numbers.push_back(j);
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main() 
{ 
      vector<int>numbers; 
      int i = 0; 
      for (int i=1; i <= 100; ++i) 
      {  
             numbers.push_back(i);  
      } 
      for(int i=100;i>0;--i)
      {
               cout << numbers[i-1] << endl;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reverse iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
vector<int> numbers(100);
for( auto it= numbers.rbegin(); it != numbers.rend(); ++it)
{
   std::cout<< *it<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    myVector.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator riter = myVector.rbegin();
while (riter != myVector.rend())
{
    std::cout << *riter << std::endl;
    ++riter;
}
```

You could use the reverse iterator here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `vector<int>` called `numbers`, the code should look something like this:

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    std::cout << numbers[i] << std::endl;
}
```

*Except* it doesn't because of integer underflow (`vector::size_type` is unsigned, so it will *never* be less than 0; the loop goes on forever). So use an iterator like the other answers suggest:

```
for (auto iterator = numbers.rbegin(); iterator != numbers.rend(); ++iterator)
{
    std::cout  << *iterator << std::endl;
}
```

Notice that StackOverflow highlights the word `iterator` in this solution, as if it's built into the language or something. It would be correct (and this solution would be broken) if you had this line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

which is yet another reason not to do things like that: it pollutes the default namespace and you can never be sure if you're using a reserved word or not.